# C++, iterator to std::map

Tags: c++, iterator, stdmap

How to declare an iterator to

```
std::map <T, Point <T> *> ,
```

where:

```
template <typename T>
struct TList
{
    typedef std::vector < std::map <T, Point <T> *> >  Type;
};
```

In the following code

```
int main ()
{
    ....
    std::map <T, Point <T> *> ::iterator i_map;  //Error
    ...
}
```

g++ shows this error:

```
error: dependent-name `  std::map<T,Point<T>*,std::less<_Key>,std::allocator<std::pair<const T, Point<T>*> > >::iterator' is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type
note: say `typename  std::map<T,Point<T>*,std::less<_Key>,std::allocator<std::pair<const T, Point<T>*> > >::iterator' if a type is meant
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `typename` as:

```
  typename std::map<T, Point <T> *>::iterator i_map;
//^^^^^^^^ here!
```

Because `iterator` is a dependent-name (as it depends on the map's *type* argument `T`), so `typename` is required here.

Read this FAQ for detail explanation:

[Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names)

Answer (score 0):

Does `typename std::map <T, Point <T> *> ::iterator i_map;` work?

Answer (score 0):

What about `typename TList<T>::Type::value_type::iterator`?

Answer (score 0):

Put "`typename`" before the line of error : `std::map <T, Point <T> *> ::iterator i_map;`.

Example:

```
typename vector<T>::iterator vIdx;
```

`// On your case : typename std::map <T, Point<T>*>::iterator i_map;`

```
vIdx= find(oVector->begin(), oVector->end(), pElementToFind); //To my case
```